# Validate multiple input values trough regular expression doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I'm trying to validate more than one input field by checking first if it's empty and then if it's a numeric non zero value. This is the HTML code:

```
<section style="" id="variations_holder">
    <div class="con_var">
        <input type="text" class="pupc" name="variation[pupc][]">
        <input type="text" class="pprice" name="variation[pprice][]">
        <input type="text" class="pqty" name="variation[pqty][]">

        <input type="text" class="pupc" name="variation[pupc][]">
        <input type="text" class="pprice" name="variation[pprice][]">
        <input type="text" class="pqty" name="variation[pqty][]">
    </div>
</section>
```

Right now there are only two set of input but can be three or more for example:

```
<section style="" id="variations_holder">
    <div class="con_var">
        <input type="text" class="pupc" name="variation[pupc][]">
        <input type="text" class="pprice" name="variation[pprice][]">
        <input type="text" class="pqty" name="variation[pqty][]">

        <input type="text" class="pupc" name="variation[pupc][]">
        <input type="text" class="pprice" name="variation[pprice][]">
        <input type="text" class="pqty" name="variation[pqty][]">

        <input type="text" class="pupc" name="variation[pupc][]">
        <input type="text" class="pprice" name="variation[pprice][]">
        <input type="text" class="pqty" name="variation[pqty][]">
    </div>
</section>
```

Since they are generated dinamically. Now this is the jQuery code I made to validate what I said before:

```
$('#variations_holder input.pprice').each(function() {
    pprice = $(this).val();
    if (!$.trim(this.value).length) {
        alert($(this).prev('label').text() + ' no se puede dejar vacío!!!');
        $(this).focus();
        is_valid = false;
        return false;
    } 

    if (pprice.match('^[1-9]\d*$') === false) {
        pprice.addClass('error');
    }
});
```

But it's not working for the following reasons:

- Only check for first field and not for the rest
- Doesn't check for regular expression since validation pass even if I write letters instead of numbers

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `return` you do returns from the callback you pass to `each` and, as you return `false`, it breaks the loop.
- `match` never returns `false`. Use [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) instead.
- you try to add a class to `pprice`, which is a string.

You can fix that like this :

```
var is_valid = true;
$('#variations_holder input.pprice').each(function() {
    pprice = $.trim(this.value);
    if (!pprice.length) {
        alert($(this).prev('label').text() + ' no se puede dejar vacío!!!');
        $(this).focus();
        is_valid = false;
    } else if (!/^[1-9]\d*$/.test(pprice)) {
        $(this).addClass('error');
        is_valid = false;
    }
});
```